SSL certificate is accepted as valid in chrome, but not in safari
My web app is deployed by Vercel, which manages certificates automatically.
When I access the web app from the chrome browser, it says "connection is secure" and "certificate is valid."
When I access the web app from the safari browser however, I see a warning that "this connection is not private." When I check the additional details, it says "certificate name does not match input."
Why would chrome consider a certificate valid when safari thinks it is invalid? What changes need to be made to ensure the web app can be securely accessed from safari?

I am trying to access the page https://www.app.example.com/path
The warning in safari says app.example.com certificate name does not match input
The CN in the Vercel dashboard is app.example.com
The certificate has not expired, according to either the vercel dashboard or the message in safari.

Screenshot from safari:

Screenshot of same page from chrome:


Check your site with SSLLabs. Make sure that you are really using exactly the same domain name in both browsers (and in the SSLLabs test), i.e. not app.example.com and www.app.example.com in the other.

You're right, it was just the www, I really thought I'd checked that. Should I delete the question?
